# $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}z^n$

Tags: calculus

I could show that $\binom{2n}{n}=(-4)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}$ and therefore by binomial theorem $\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{2n}{n}z^n=(1-4z)^{-1/2}$.

Now I want to calculate $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}z^n$. Can I use the above result somehow?

In my calculations I used $\binom{2n}{n}=\dots=4^n\frac{(n-1/2)(n-3/2)\dots 1/2}{n!}=(-4)^n(-1)^n\frac{1/2(1/2+1)\dots (1/2+n-1)}{n!}=(-4)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}$ and in the last step

[image]

Comment: Integrate the first series.

Comment: By the way, $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the $n$-th Catalan number. See here for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @AlannRosas So the solution should be $\frac{1}{z}\int (1-4z)^{-1/2}dz$? Because according to mathematica it should be something else or I made some mistake

Comment: @user826130 what did you get for $\int(1-4z)^{-1/2}dz$? Also, remember the integration constant $C$; that might've played a role in why your answer didn't coincide with a CAS's.

Comment: I get $-\frac{\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$ so dividing by $z$ gives us $-\frac{\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$ but the solution should be $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$

Comment: You're forgetting that $\int(1-4z)^{-1/2}dz=-\frac{\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}+C$ for some constant $C$. This constant can be determined by evaluating the series you obtained at $z=0$. You'll get $C=\frac{1}{2}$, from which the correct sum immediately follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}z^n
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1z\int_0^z\binom{2n}{n}t^n dt\\
&=\frac1z\int_0^z\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}t^n dt\\
&=\frac1z\int_0^z \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-4t}}\\
&=\frac1z\left[-\frac{\sqrt{1-4t}}2\right]_0^z\\
&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.
\end{align}$$